# Py4JError: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonUtils.getEncryptionEnabled does not exist in the JVM in DSVM

Tags: pyspark, azure-dsvm

I am using a python script that establish pyspark environment in jupyter notebook. The kernel is **Azure ML 3.6**

```
#find SPARK_HOME Variable environment
import findspark
findspark.init()

import pyspark;
import os
# These reference the jars mentioned on the Snowflake documentation page
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages net.snowflake:snowflake-jdbc:3.6.24,net.snowflake:spark-snowflake_2.11:2.4.12-spark_2.3,com.microsoft.ml.spark:mmlspark_2.11:0.18.0 pyspark-shell'

from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, SparkSession

# Use the SparkSession API for datasets and dataframe API 
spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local').appName('test').config('spark.driver.memory', '6G').config('spark.driver.maxResultSize', '4G').config("spark.num.executors","8").config("spark.executor.cores", "8").config('spark.executor.memory', '14G').config("spark.worker.instances", "2").getOrCreate()
```

but I receive this error :
Py4JError: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonUtils.getEncryptionEnabled does not exist in the JVM

I don't understand why. this code yesterday was working perfectly but today I receive this error.

Comment: Did you upgrade / downgrade your spark version ?

Comment: nope I didn't modify anything in my spark version. it's 2.4

Comment: sorry it's 2.3.2

Comment: What version of Py4J do you use ?

Comment: py4j version : 0.10.7

Comment: Can you add the Py4J path in you SPARK_HOME ?

Comment: can you specify how please ? I am trying to change the PYTHONPATH variable from cmdline in Juypter notebook but it is not changing. any suggestions how should I do that please ?